# Page component is not rendering again even when the app state changes in the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-router and redux together, when I update the state of the store. The component is not re-rendered, and therefore the redirect does not work.

Here is my code.

The store code:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {signInWithPhoneNumber} from '../../modules/auth/actions/authSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: signInWithPhoneNumber
  }
})

export default store
```

Here I'm passing in the store

```
import AppRouting from "./config/routes"
import store from "./store/store"
import firebase from "firebase"
import firebaseConfig from "../config/firebase-config"

function renderUI() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRouting />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    ,
    document.querySelector("#root"))
}
```

I put this switch component in a BrowserRouter

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import React from "react"
import Login from "../pages/login"
import SignUp from "../pages/sign-up"
import ConfirmPhone from "../pages/confirm-number"

function AuthRoutes(props) {
    
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/confirmPhone">
                <ConfirmPhone />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

In the Login page after the verification code is sent I must load the ConfirmPhone component redirecting the user to the /confirmPhone path.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import M from 'materialize-css';
import Header from "../components/header"
import Button from "../../../components/Button"
import Dialog from "../../../components/Dialog"
import InputText from "../../../components/TextInput"
import truncateString from "../lib/truncateString"
import { onTextChange, onSubmitForm, onSubmitConfirm, openDialogOnLogIn } from "../config/ui-events"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { selectAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "../actions/authSlice"
import { actions } from "../actions/authSlice"



function Login(props) {
    const [phoneField, setPhoneField] = useState('')
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(2)
    const openDialog = false
    const currentAuth = useSelector(selectAuth)
    const { signInWithPhoneNumber } = actions
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    function onChangePhone(evt) {
        const inputValue = evt.target.value
        setPhoneField(truncateString(inputValue, 8))
        setValid(onTextChange(evt, inputValue, /\d{8}?/))
    }

    function onSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()

        dispatch(signInWithPhoneNumber({ status: 2, session: null }))
    }

    if (currentAuth.status === 2) {
        console.log(currentAuth)
        return (<Redirect to="/confirmPhone" />)
    } else {

        return (
            <section className="login">
                <div className="login__layout">
                    <Header>
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                    </Header>
                    <form>
                        <p>Accede a tu cuenta</p>
                        <InputText id="phone-number"
                            pattern="\d{8}"
                            errorMessage="Incorrect phone format for +505 area code"
                            successMessage="The phone format is correct"
                            helperMessage="Type a phone number of +505 area code"
                            labelText="Telefono"
                            changeHandler={onChangePhone}
                            validationState={valid}
                            value={phoneField} />
                        <div>
                            <Button clickHandler={onSubmit} text="Entrar" classes="login__signIn" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="recaptcha-container" className="login__captcha">

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }

}

export default Login
```

when the status field of the status changes to 2, I need to do a redirect instead of loading the Login component again.

But even if the state changes, the component is not even re-rendered.

Can anyone help me see what happens?

In this file, I create the slice which retrieves me the reducer,action and the selector.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    value: {
      status: 0
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    signInWithPhoneNumber: (state, action) => {
      alert("authentication will update the store")
      state.auth = action.payload
    }
  },
});

const selectAuth = (state) => state.auth
const signInWithPhoneNumber = slice.reducer
const actions = slice.actions

export { signInWithPhoneNumber, selectAuth, signIn, actions }
```

the reducer function `signInWithPhoneNumber` is the one I use to update the state.

Comment: Your reducer looks fine, what does `console.log(currentAuth)` log? I think it may be your selector that is selecting the wrong slice from the state.

Comment: Where is `selectAuth` defined?

Comment: Thanks for try to help me, is defined in the same file in which I've created the slice, in that file I've also exported the action and the reducer function, I've updated the question to show that code.

Comment: console.log(currentAuth) prints an object {status: 2,session: null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your auth object is inside another auth object so your selector should look like this. It's because when you create store you wrap it inside auth and then when you run action also wrap payload inside auth.

```
const selectAuth = (state) => state.auth.auth;
```

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: signInWithPhoneNumber // wrap inside auth
  }
});

signInWithPhoneNumber: (state, action) => {
  state.auth = action.payload // wrap inside another auth
},
```